# How to run a build on closing PR in CircleCi?

Tags: github, circleci

I create some preview environments using kubernetes when CI is run against a PR. Is it possible to run a CI job in CircleCI during closing the PR, so that i can delete those preview environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly as you might imagine no. At least I can't think of anything.

As long as you have frequent enough builds though, you can have a step that looks for running pods in K8s and matches them to PRs. Then if the PR is closed, remove the pod.

In this manner, the environment wouldn't be deleted as soon as the PR is closed, but on the very next build that runs.

Alternatively, if you don't have frequent builds, you can create a CircleCI Scheduled Workflow that runs once an hour with a single job of pruning old K8s pods.

Comment: `CircleCI Scheduled Workflow` is a TIL for me. Thanks let me try that out.